# Safely deleting a Django model from the database using a transaction

Tags: database, django, postgresql, django-models, transactions

In my Django application, I have code that deletes a single instance of a model from the database. There is a possibility that two concurrent requests could both try to delete the same model at the same time. In this case, I want one request to succeed and the other to fail. How can I do this?

The problem is that when deleting a instance with `delete()`, Django doesn't return any information about whether the command was successful or not. This code illustrates the problem:

```
b0 = Book.objects.get(id=1)
b1 = Book.objects.get(id=1)
b0.delete()
b1.delete()
```

Only one of these two `delete()` commands actually deleted the object, but I don't know which one. No exceptions are thrown and nothing is returned to indicate the success of the command. In pure SQL, the command would return the number of rows deleted and if the value was 0, I would know my delete failed.

I am using PostgreSQL with the default Read Commited isolation level. My understanding of this level is that each command (SELECT, DELETE, etc.) sees a snapshot of the database, but that the next command could see a different snapshot of the database. I believe this means I can't do something like this:

```
# I believe this wont work
@commit_on_success
def view(request):
  try:
    book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
    # Possibility that the instance is deleted by the other request
    # before we get to the next delete()
    book.delete()
  except ObjectDoesntExist:
    # Already been deleted
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the constraint right into the SQL DELETE statement by using QuerySet.delete instead of Model.delete:

```
Book.objects.filter(pk=1).delete()
```

This will never issue the SELECT query at all, just something along the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM Book WHERE id=1;
```

That handles the race condition of two concurrent requests deleting the same record at the same time, but it doesn't let you know whether your delete got there first. For that you would have to get the raw cursor (which [django lets you do](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/)), .execute() the above DELETE yourself, and then pick up the cursor's [rowcount](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount) attribute, which will be 0 if you didn't wind up deleting anything.